# p1_colour is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Please read over my code:

```
#Tron

from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
import os

#####Setting The Variables
canvas_height = 500
canvas_width = 600
canvas_colour = "#C9BFBF"

p1_x = (2*canvas_width)/8
p1_y = (2*canvas_height)/8
p2_x = (6*canvas_width)/8
p2_y = (2*canvas_height)/8
p3_x = (2*canvas_width)/8
p3_y = (6*canvas_height)/8
p4_x = (6*canvas_width)/8
p4_y = (6*canvas_height)/8

#p1_colour = input("{Player 1}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#os.system("cls")
#p2_colour = input("{Player 2}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#os.system("cls")
#while p1_colour == p2_colour:
#    p2_colour = input("{Player 2}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#    os.system("cls")
#p3_colour = input("{Player 3}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#os.system("cls")
#while p3_colour == p2_colour or p3_colour == p1_colour:
#    p3_colour = input("{Player 3}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#    os.system("cls")
#p4_colour = input("{Player 4}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#os.system("cls")
#while p4_colour == p3_colour or p4_colour == p2_colour or p4_colour == p1_colour:
#    p4_colour = input("{Player 4}Input your colour please. Or use a hex value.")
#    os.system("cls")

line_width = 7
line_length = 7

#os.system("cls")

##Some defining...

def p1_red():
    global p1_color
    p1_colour = "red"
    p1_choice = 1
def p1_blue():
    global p1_color
    p1_colour = "blue"
    p1_choice = 1
def p1_yellow():
    global p1_color
    p1_colour = "yellow"
    p1_choice = 1
def p1_purple():
    global p1_color
    p1_colour = "purple"
    p1_choice = 1
def p1_black():
    global p1_color
    p1_colour = "black"
    p1_choice = 1


def p2_red():
    global p2_color
    p2_colour = "red"
    p2_choice = 1
def p2_blue():
    global p2_color
    p2_colour = "blue"
    p2_choice = 1
def p2_yellow():
    global p2_color
    p2_colour = "yellow"
    p2_choice = 1
def p2_purple():
    global p2_color
    p2_colour = "purple"
    p2_choice = 1
def p2_black():
    global p2_color
    p2_colour = "black"
    p2_choice = 1


def p3_red():
    global p3_color
    p3_colour = "red"
    p3_choice = 1
def p3_blue():
    global p3_color
    p3_colour = "blue"
    p3_choice = 1
def p3_yellow():
    global p3_color
    p3_colour = "yellow"
    p3_choice = 1
def p3_purple():
    global p3_color
    p3_colour = "purple"
    p3_choice = 1
def p3_black():
    global p3_color
    p3_colour = "black"
    p3_choice = 1


def p4_red():
    global p4_color
    p4_colour = "red"
    p4_choice = 1
def p4_blue():
    global p4_color
    p4_colour = "blue"
    p4_choice = 1
def p4_yellow():
    global p4_color
    p4_colour = "yellow"
    p4_choice = 1
def p4_purple():
    global p4_color
    p4_colour = "purple"
    p4_choice = 1
def p4_black():
    global p4_color
    p4_colour = "black"
    p4_choice = 1



def Game():
    ####Main Window
    window = Toplevel()
    window.title("Tron")
    canvas = Canvas(window, bg = canvas_colour, height=canvas_height, width=canvas_width, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.grid()

    menu = Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=menu)

    ###defining the drop down menu....
    def quit(self):
        global window
        window.destroy()
    def key_bind(*args):
        global Tk
        global canvas_colour
        global canvas_height
        global canvas_width
        window2 = Tk()
        window2.title("Key Bindings")
        canvas2 = Frame(bg = canvas_colour, height=canvas_height, width=canvas_width, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas2.grid()    
        text = Text(window2)
        text.insert(INSERT, "Key Bindings\nWASD = Player 1 movement\nIJKL = Player 2 movement\nArrow Keys = Player 3 movement\n8462 = Player 4 movement\nEsc key = Quit")
        text.grid()
        window2.mainloop()

    Drive_location = "Tron_img.gif"

    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = Drive_location)
    canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

    subMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = subMenu)
    subMenu.add_command(label="Key Bindings", command=key_bind)
    subMenu.add_separator()
    subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)


    ####Functions
    # player controls

    ##p1

    def p1_move_N(self):
        global p1_y
        canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
        p1_y = p1_y - line_length

    def p1_move_S(self):
        global p1_y
        canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x + line_length, p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
        p1_y = p1_y + line_length

    def p1_move_E(self):
        global p1_x
        canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x + line_length), p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
        p1_x = p1_x + line_length

    def p1_move_W(self):
        global p1_x
        canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x - line_length, p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
        p1_x = p1_x - line_length

    ##p2

    def p2_move_N(self):
        global p2_y
        canvas.create_line(p2_x, p2_y, p2_x, (p2_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=p2_colour)
        p2_y = p2_y - line_length

    def p2_move_S(self):
        global p2_y
        canvas.create_line(p2_x, p2_y, p2_x + line_length, p2_y, width=line_width, fill=p2_colour)
        p2_y = p2_y + line_length

    def p2_move_E(self):
        global p2_x
        canvas.create_line(p2_x, p2_y, (p2_x + line_length), p2_y, width=line_width, fill=p2_colour)
        p2_x = p2_x + line_length

    def p2_move_W(self):
        global p2_x
        canvas.create_line(p2_x, p2_y, p2_x - line_length, p2_y, width=line_width, fill=p2_colour)
        p2_x = p2_x - line_length

    ##p3

    def p3_move_N(self):
        global p3_y
        canvas.create_line(p3_x, p3_y, p3_x, (p3_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=p3_colour)
        p3_y = p3_y - line_length

    def p3_move_S(self):
        global p3_y
        canvas.create_line(p3_x, p3_y, p3_x + line_length, p3_y, width=line_width, fill=p3_colour)
        p3_y = p3_y + line_length

    def p3_move_E(self):
        global p3_x
        canvas.create_line(p3_x, p3_y, (p3_x + line_length), p3_y, width=line_width, fill=p3_colour)
        p3_x = p3_x + line_length

    def p3_move_W(self):
        global p3_x
        canvas.create_line(p3_x, p3_y, p3_x - line_length, p3_y, width=line_width, fill=p3_colour)
        p3_x = p3_x - line_length

    ##p4

    def p4_move_N(self):
        global p4_y
        canvas.create_line(p4_x, p4_y, p4_x, (p4_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=p4_colour)
        p4_y = p4_y - line_length

    def p4_move_S(self):
        global p4_y
        canvas.create_line(p4_x, p4_y, p4_x + line_length, p4_y, width=line_width, fill=p4_colour)
        p4_y = p4_y + line_length

    def p4_move_E(self):
        global p4_x
        canvas.create_line(p4_x, p4_y, (p4_x + line_length), p4_y, width=line_width, fill=p4_colour)
        p4_x = p4_x + line_length

    def p4_move_W(self):
        global p4_x
        canvas.create_line(p4_x, p4_y, p4_x - line_length, p4_y, width=line_width, fill=p4_colour)
        p4_x = p4_x - line_length

    #######bind movement to key presses

    ##p1
    window.bind("w", p1_move_N)
    window.bind("s", p1_move_S)
    window.bind("a", p1_move_W)
    window.bind("d", p1_move_E)

    ##p2
    window.bind("i", p2_move_N)
    window.bind("k", p2_move_S)
    window.bind("j", p2_move_W)
    window.bind("l", p2_move_E)

    ##p3
    window.bind("<Up>", p3_move_N)
    window.bind("<Down>", p3_move_S)
    window.bind("<Left>", p3_move_W)
    window.bind("<Right>", p3_move_E)

    ##p4
    window.bind("8", p4_move_N)
    window.bind("2", p4_move_S)
    window.bind("4", p4_move_W)
    window.bind("6", p4_move_E)

    window.bind("<Key-Escape>", quit)

    window.mainloop()

#############
colors = Tk()
colors.title("Tron - Character Colours")
frame = Frame(colors)
frame.grid()
colors.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', '1')

p1_button_red = Button(colors, text="P1 - Red", command=p1_red)
p1_button_red.grid(row=0, column=0)
p1_button_blu = Button(colors, text="P1 - Blue", command=p1_blue)
p1_button_blu.grid(row=0, column=1)
p1_button_yel = Button(colors, text="P1 - Yellow", command=p1_yellow)
p1_button_yel.grid(row=0, column=2)
p1_button_pur = Button(colors, text="P1 - Purple", command=p1_purple)
p1_button_pur.grid(row=0, column=3)
p1_button_bla = Button(colors, text="P1 - Black", command=p1_black)
p1_button_bla.grid(row=0, column=4)

p2_button_red = Button(colors, text="P2 - Red", command=p2_red)
p2_button_red.grid(row=1, column=0)
p2_button_blu = Button(colors, text="P2 - Blue", command=p2_blue)
p2_button_blu.grid(row=1, column=1)
p2_button_yel = Button(colors, text="P2 - Yellow", command=p2_yellow)
p2_button_yel.grid(row=1, column=2)
p2_button_pur = Button(colors, text="P2 - Purple", command=p2_purple)
p2_button_pur.grid(row=1, column=3)
p2_button_bla = Button(colors, text="P2 - Black", command=p2_black)
p2_button_bla.grid(row=1, column=4)

p3_button_red = Button(colors, text="P3 - Red", command=p3_red)
p3_button_red.grid(row=2, column=0)
p3_button_blu = Button(colors, text="P3 - Blue", command=p3_blue)
p3_button_red.grid(row=2, column=1)
p3_button_yel = Button(colors, text="P3 - Yellow", command=p3_yellow)
p3_button_red.grid(row=2, column=2)
p3_button_pur = Button(colors, text="P3 - Purple", command=p3_purple)
p3_button_red.grid(row=2, column=3)
p3_button_bla = Button(colors, text="P3 - Black", command=p3_black)
p3_button_red.grid(row=2, column=4)

p4_button_red = Button(colors, text="P4 - Red", command=p4_red)
p4_button_red.grid(row=3, column=0)
p4_button_blu = Button(colors, text="P4 - Blue", command=p4_blue)
p4_button_red.grid(row=3, column=1)
p4_button_yel = Button(colors, text="P4 - Yellow", command=p4_yellow)
p4_button_red.grid(row=3, column=2)
p4_button_pur = Button(colors, text="P4 - Purple", command=p4_purple)
p4_button_red.grid(row=3, column=3)
p4_button_bla = Button(colors, text="P4 - Black", command=p4_black)
p4_button_red.grid(row=3, column=4)

next_but = Button(colors, text="Next", command = Game)
next_but.grid(row=5, column=0)

colors.mainloop()
```

Comment: ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global p3_color
p3_colour = "red"
```

You are missing a "u" in your `global` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much...I have spent about 20 minutes trying to work out what was wrong (facepalm) :D